# Delphi FMX button calling a dll form dosent wait till the form is finished with before exiting routone

Tags: forms, delphi, dll, firemonkey

I have a dll that creates a form and uses strings passed to it to set up variables for database connections. This all works fine. My problem is on my main form I need to refresh some DB tables when the dll form is closed. How do I do this.

my dll is

```
library Contact;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  FMX.Forms,
  NewContact in 'NewContact.pas' {FMNewContact};

{$R *.res}

procedure NewContactShow(Title: string;
                         Table: string;
                         Connection: String;
                         Param: TStrings); StdCall export;
begin
  FMNewContact := TFMNewContact.Create(nil); // creates the form
  FMNewContact.TableName := Table;
  with FMNewContact do
  begin
    Caption := Title;
    FDConnect.ConnectionName := Connection;
    FDConnect.Params.Text := Param.Text;
    FDConnect.Connected := True;
    Saved := False; //Flag to say the Form new data has been saved to db table; 
    Show;
  end;
end;

function GetStatus(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := FMNewContact.Saved; // get status of flag before destroying form.
  FMNewContact.Destroy;
end;

exports
  NewContactShow,
  GetStatus;

begin
end.
```

In my Main form

```
procedure TForm1.NewBttnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    // Creates the form and displays in fine.
    NewContactShow('Enter New Employee',
                   'Employee',
                   FDTimeCard.ConnectionName,
                   FDTimeCard.Params);
  finally
    // This destroys the form before user can deal with it 
    if GetStatus then
      BuildEmployeeTable(); 
  end;
end;
```

If I remove the GetStatus check Tables are updated prior to the user entering infomation on the dll form

So goal is

I need to call Dll form.
Wait till user saved data on form.
Update Table on screen.

Comment: Call ShowModal instead of show...

Comment: Why that is an recognized statement.

Comment: Sorry Brain malfunction. Spelling mistake. Found out reason. ShowModal holds will form closed. Awesome thanks for that.

Comment: `export` is ignored, remove it